# AttachToIE seems to be non-existent in the WatiN 2.0 RC

Tags: watin, popupwindow

IE.AttachToIE(Find.ByUrl("my url") seems to be non-existent  in the WatiN 2.0 RC candidate. It does exist in 1.3. How can I fix it in 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
IE.AttachTo<IE>(Find.ByUrl("my url"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Browser ie = Browser.AttachTo(typeof(IE), Find.ByTitle(new Regex("Window Title.*")));